# Lambda expression -- apply logical not to a boolean method call

Tags: c#, lambda

This must have a simple answer -- I have a piece of code that looks like this ...

```
condition = Expression.Call(memberAccess,
                        typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"),
                        Expression.Constant(value));
                    lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
```

it works great ... BUT I also want a NotContains.  Am I going to have to write an extension method or is there a way to simply do a ![lambda] ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Surround with `Expression.Not`:

```
condition = Expression.Not(Expression.Call(memberAccess,
                    typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"),
                    Expression.Constant(value)));
lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
```